# AWS Cognito - Get user data after login with SignInUI

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I followed the instructions at [Add AWS Mobile User Sign In](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html)

The code looks like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
                SignInUI signIn = (SignInUI) AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(LoginActivity.this, SignInUI.class);
                signIn.login(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class).execute(); 
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I get the public claims for the logged in user (ie email, name etc.) so I can know who logged in? The only ways I've seen is to do it is manually which seems to require a client secret which I obviously don't have as this is a client side mobile app.

Comment: Hi @yitzih  i'm also in same issue, how did you resolve that issue then ?

Comment: The answer below was the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS Cognito Documentation I found this:

[image: Step 7 of AWS Cognito Tutorial for Integrating User Pools for Android apps]

The complete tutorial for previous steps can be found on: [Tutorial: Integrating User Pools for Android apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-user-details-android%20this)